# Help with Enum extension methods

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have `enum` helper generic class where i have method `EnumDescription()`
To call it i have to go like that `EnumHelper<Enumtype>.EnumDescription(value)`
I want to implement `enum` extension method `EnumDescription(this Enum value)` which based on my enum helper method `EnumHelper<T>.EnumDescription(value)`

There one thing I am stuck with. Here is my code:

```
public static string EnumDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();

    return EnumHelper<type>.EnumDescription(value); //Error here
}
```

I am getting an error `The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Are you trying to give an Enum a nice description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options that I can think of (there may be more).

First option: make the extension method generic. C# doesn't allow `enum` as a generic constraint, which means that you'll need a runtime check to ensure that the type is, in fact, an `enum`.

```
public static string EnumDescription<T>(this T value)
    where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Type argument T must be an enum.");

    return EnumHelper<T>.EnumDescription(value);
}
```

Second option: use reflection. This will be slow(er), although you could create a delegate from the `MethodInfo` and cache it for re-use in a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` or similar. That way you'd only incur the cost of reflection the first time that particular type was encountered.

```
public static string EnumDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type t = value.GetType();
    Type g = typeof(EnumHelper<>).MakeGenericType(t);
    MethodInfo mi = g.GetMethod("EnumDescription");
    return (string)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
}
```

Comment: what do you think which option is better?

Answer (score 1):

Generics are done at compile-time.

You can either change your method to a generic method `where T : struct` or call the inner method using Reflection.